# Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory [JSP Servlets and MySQL]

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets, glassfish

I was having the following error: `java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Cannot open file:C:\AppServers\glassfish5\glassfish\domains\domain1/config/keystore.jks [Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect])`

Solved it by simply adding `useSSL=false` on MySQL database connection and `JDBC_URL` String in class DBConnection.

**Database Connection**

```
package data;

import java.sql.*;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource;

public class DBConnection {
    
    private static final String JDBC_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/course_management_system?zeroDateTimeBehavior=CONVERT_TO_NULL&useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=UTC";
    private static final String JDBC_USER = "root";
    private static final String JDBC_PASSWORD = "admin";

    private static BasicDataSource dataSource;

    public static DataSource getDataSource() {
        if (dataSource == null) {
            dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
            dataSource.setUrl(JDBC_URL);
            dataSource.setUsername(JDBC_USER);
            dataSource.setPassword(JDBC_PASSWORD);
            dataSource.setInitialSize(50);
            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
            }
        }
        return dataSource;
    }

    public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        return getDataSource().getConnection();
    }

    public static void close(ResultSet rs) {
        try {
            rs.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }
    }

    public static void close(PreparedStatement stmt) {
        try {
            stmt.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }
    }

    public static void close(Connection conn) {
        try {
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }
    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>mb</groupId>
    <artifactId>CourseManagementSystem</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>CourseManagementSystem</name>
    
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        <jakartaee>8.0</jakartaee>
    </properties>
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jakartaee}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.22</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    
     <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>${jakartaee}</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**The error**

```
CourseManagementSystem was successfully deployed in 316 milliseconds.|#]
  java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Cannot open file:C:\AppServers\glassfish5\glassfish\domains\domain1/config/keystore.jks [Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect])
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:656)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:534)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:734)
    at data.DBConnection.getConnection(DBConnection.java:35)
    at data.UserDAO.list(UserDAO.java:30)
    at web.UserController.doGet(UserController.java:18)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:645)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:750)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:611)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:550)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:114)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:332)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:199)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:463)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:242)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Cannot open file:C:\AppServers\glassfish5\glassfish\domains\domain1/config/keystore.jks [Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:110)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:70)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:833)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:453)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:198)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:52)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:357)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:103)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:652)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.SSLParamsException: Cannot open file:C:\AppServers\glassfish5\glassfish\domains\domain1/config/keystore.jks [Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.ExportControlled.getSSLContext(ExportControlled.java:550)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.ExportControlled.performTlsHandshake(ExportControlled.java:303)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.performTlsHandshake(StandardSocketFactory.java:188)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.performTlsHandshake(NativeSocketConnection.java:97)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.negotiateSSLConnection(NativeProtocol.java:333)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeAuthenticationProvider.connect(NativeAuthenticationProvider.java:167)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.connect(NativeProtocol.java:1350)
    at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:157)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:953)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:823)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:782)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:56)
    at sun.security.provider.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(KeyStoreDelegator.java:224)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$DualFormatJKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:70)
    at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1445)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.ExportControlled.getSSLContext(ExportControlled.java:530)
    ... 51 more
Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Password verification failed
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:780)
    ... 56 more
|#]
  StandardWrapperValve[web.UserController]: Servlet.service() for servlet web.UserController threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at data.DBConnection.close(DBConnection.java:40)
    at data.UserDAO.list(UserDAO.java:51)
    at web.UserController.doGet(UserController.java:18)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:645)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:750)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:611)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:550)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:114)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:332)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:199)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:463)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:242)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
|#]
```

**SOLUTION**

I solved the issue adding `useSSL=false` to the DB Connection string.

Comment: It looks like one of your close calls `DBConnection.close(rs);`, `DBConnection.close(stmt);` or `DBConnection.close(conn);` is passing a null object to the close method` Debug your code to work out which one is null, and why it is null (Has it already closed?) then either check for null or catch the null and do something to resolve it. Just to check, was your code actually getting users from the database?

Comment: Where's the rest of the stack trace? Likely something in the `try` block threw, leaving `rs` or `stmt` (or even `conn`) null and threw NPE in the `finally` block.  We need to see the complete stack trace.  ALWAYS include the complete stack trace.

Comment: @sorifiend I marked a debugging point but when i run the web-app in debugging mode i can't go forward any line. Don't know how to search for the null value.

Comment: @JimGarrison I've just added the complete stack trace. Sorry

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with your code, the NPE is just a side-effect of the much more serious issue that Java doesn't like the file you've given it as your keystore.  Start there.

Comment: Specifically this line which spells out your issue `Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Cannot open file:C:\AppServers\glassfish5\glassfish\domains\domain1/config/keystore.jks [Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect]` check and fix your keystone or password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem by adding `useSSL=false` in the database URL.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem has nothing whatsoever to do with NullPointerException. Your exception handling is bad, and you need to fix it, so that you don't get confused again.

### The problem

Your exception handling scheme boils down to: "Print some information to standard out **and just keep going**". That last bit is the problem: Your code was not written with the notion that every line may simply do something, or nothing, depending on whether exceptions happen. Thus, your code keeps rolling and because things aren't in a state you expected, further errors occur, and these errors are **completely irrelevant** - they are not the problem, but they clog the logs and confuse you.

The right strategy to deal with exceptions is **to deal with them**. "Whatever, just print it out and keep on going" is not dealing with them. If you can't deal with them (and that's the common case), then just let the exception bubble up. Do not catch it unless you can write code that solves the problem. An exception that nothing can handle *should* bubble all the way up and roll up the thread, that's the best solution, and also the least code, so that's a win-win.

Methods that clearly are intended to interact with the database **should** be declared to `throws SQLException`, and your `public static void main` method **should** be declared to `throws Exception`, which is allowed.

If you somehow MUST catch a checked exception even if you don't know what to do (that's bad), then at least put; `throw new RuntimeException("Unhandled", e);` in your catch block, instead of `e.printStackTrace(System.out).

### Your actual exception issue

Your mysql driver is trying to load a corrupted keystore. That's a rather tricky problem.

Most likely you've added a configuration (or a default configuration is being applied) that expects a keystore file at
`C:\AppServers\glassfish5\glassfish\domains\domain1/config/keystore.jks` - I don't think the problem is the mix of slashes (java usually understands this just fine), but I bet that file doesn't exist. Alternatively, you tried to make it, an exception occured, and the same deplorable exception handling has resulted in you not realizing that the keyfile is corrupt. Check the file - it's probably not there at all, or at 0 bytes. (Re)generate it, or fix the configuration.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I've located the file and it's 5KB, so i can say it's not empty. I've read that sometimes GlassFish changes the default password in some versions from _changeme_ to _changeit_. I can't read the file properly, don't know how. And i've not found how to edit it. The rare thing is that i have another web-app with a similar code, working just fine, creating it with exactly the same procedure.

Comment: The `keytool` tool (it's in your JDK distribution, next to `jar` and `javac` and such) can be used. Search the web for tutorials on how to invoke it (it's a command line tool).